# Prepare Macros which add comma after every 10 digit in a column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I was trying to add a comma after every 10 digits in a column. However I have succeeded in creating macros.

Meanwhile I am facing another challenge because the data has 20 columns (Range A1:A20)[Raw Data snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4GkP.jpg) and I need to run the macros each time by clicking on different columns.

Please help whether it can be done in a single macro for all the columns.

Comment: This is not a coding service... What have you tried?

Comment: Sub AddCommas()
Dim s As String
    s = Selection.Value
    Dim x As Long
    x = Len(s) \ 10
    If Len(s) Mod 10 = 0 Then
        x = x - 1
    End If
    Do Until x <= 0
        s = Left(s, x * 10) & "," & Mid(s, x * 10 + 1)
        x = x - 1
    Loop
    Selection.Value = s

Comment: However it works only in a particular column

Comment: @ADAvishek - In order to get that code to process multiple columns, or even a single column (at the moment it only works for a single cell), you will need to add some loops to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, it should work for you,

```
Sub AddCommas()
Dim s As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
For k = 1 To 20
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    s = ""
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, k).Value) And Int(Len(Cells(i, k)) / 10) >= 1 Then
        For j = 1 To Int(Len(Cells(i, k).Value) / 10) + 1
            If j = 1 Then
                s = s & Left(Cells(i, k).Value, j * 10) & ","
            Else
            If j = (Int(Len(Cells(i, k).Value) / 10) + 1) Or (Len(Cells(i, k).Value) / 10) = j Then
                s = s & Mid(Cells(i, k).Value, ((j - 1) * 10) + 1, 10)
            Else
                s = s & Mid(Cells(i, k).Value, ((j - 1) * 10) + 1, 10) & ","
            End If
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, k).Value = s
    End If
Next i
Next k
End Sub
```

Adjust the `k` variable and `i` variable as per your starting row position and number of columns. Hope this helps.

Comment: Syntax error is popping up.

Comment: Tried adding some loops however failed

Comment: @ADAvishek it works perfectly for me. Fix those syntax error and try. Those should have occurred during copy/paste

Comment: Cool I will write it down this time

Comment: I am getting error in the below coding (If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, k).Value) And Int(Len(Cells(i, k)) / 10) >= 1 ) ( If j = (Int(Len(Cells(i, k).Value) / 10) + 1) Or (Len(Cells(i, 
k).Value) / 10) = j Then)

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of my data. You can have a re-look

Comment: I think you have not properly pasted the `then` in that line

Comment: I will check again

Comment: @ADAvishek I have edited it. Please copy paste the code and try as it is

Comment: Awesome  it works. Any way the system hanged everytime i used this macro. does it depends on the data

Comment: For now you can change the `Rows.Count` to a value which is the last non empty row in your excel. It usually hangs for a while as there are 20 columns*65K rows

Comment: @ADAvishek give an approx value of 100 or 500 . The macro will run faster. Please upvote and mark my answer as correct if you found this helpful

Comment: definitely it has been done

Comment: @ADAvishek Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks to u gowtham